Detective anime with two men trying to help a girl with a monkey companion
Back in 2004 at a convention, I was in an anime watching room and came across an anime about some kind of detective or mercenary trying to help a girl with a monkey companion. She lost her spot in a princess lottery? I can't remember if she needed their help to get back in or find a lost friend. The two men helped her and I remember them because it was a black and white team and the black guy wasn't a Japanese stereotypical/racist depiction of a black man. No lips like Jinx or Mr. Popo. I've been to so many people. No one has any idea what I'm talking about.
The animation reminded me of either Pokémon or Read or Die. Please help. I really want to finish watching it. I have no idea if it was a film or had episodes.
Also, I think they were in a alternate world because something was weird with the Eiffel Tower. It was either in half or crooked.

Did the anime seem to be set in France? Who appeared to be the protagonist—the girl or the detectives/mercenaries? Is it a slice-of-life type of anime?
